# Check if any key is pressed Javascript without a form

Tags: javascript, html

```
if (any key is pressed){
Hide a div.
}
```

I am wondering if there is an easy way to detect if any key is pressed without an input.

Comment: I'm not sure, but can you add an `onKeyPress` function to the body?

Comment: Probably the most suitable place would be to attach a `keypress` event handler to `document`, but you could, alternatively, attach it to `window`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
document.onkeypress=function(e){
    //do the required work
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Attach the `keypress` event in body or other element you want. Something like

```
<body onkeypress="myFunction()">
```

**Or**

```
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', myFunction);
```

**Funciton Definition**

```
function myFunction(){
     //do what you want after key is pressed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you didnt tag it jQuery, but if you are willing to try a jQUery solution check [This Page](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/)

take note that jQuery is simply a huge javascript extension file which is available for free on their website.

Comment: Would probably be more suitable as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I have never used JQuery, it's on my to do list. For now i've used one of the JS solutions. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

An example of attaching a `keypress` event handler with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) to `window`, and how to be sure to clean it up on `unload` with [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener)

CSS

```
.hideMe {
    display:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="hideOnKeyPress">Now you see me.</div>
```

Javascript

```
var hideOnKeyPress = document.getElementById('hideOnKeyPress');

function pressed() {
    hideOnKeyPress.classList.add('hideMe');
}

function unload() {
    window.removeEventListener('keypress', pressed, false);
    window.removeEventListener('unload', unload, false);
}

window.addEventListener('keypress', pressed, false);
window.addEventListener('unload', unload, false);
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7rzbg/)